# How to handle nav-back navigation for custom app in BTP Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: javascript, navigation, sapui5, url-routing, sap-fiori

I have this launchpad composed of mainly 4 custom tiles.
[MyLaunchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVn9s.png)
[image]

The custom tile itself is a freestyle SAPUI5 app. In that app, I call a service to reflect a number on the tile. For example, SOLPED tile has a "1". When i click on this tile, it navigates to its associated app, and when I click on the nav-back arrow inside the main app, it navigates back to the launchpad.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIFqm.png)
[image]

The numbers on the launchpad tiles could change due to user actions inside their respective main apps; so, is there any way to handle a new function call to my service in the custom tile when navigating back from the main app?

What I have tried is:

1- Handle the navigation using routing

**Manifest.json**

```
"routes": [
                {
                    "name": "RouteTileSolped",
                    "pattern": ":?query:",
                    "target": [
                        "TargetTileSolped"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "TargetTileSolped": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearControlAggregation": false,
                    "viewId": "ViewTileSolped",
                    "viewName": "View1"
                }
            }
```

**View1.controller.js**

```
//Inicializar Routing
onInit: function(){
...
 let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
 oRouter.getRoute("RouteTileSolped").attachPatternMatched(this._onNavBack, this);
},

_onNavBack: function(){
 console.log("NAVBACK!!! ROUTING!!!");
},
```

It doesn't console logs after clicking the nav back button.

2- Using ShellUIService

**View1.controller.js**

```
onBeforeRendering: async function(){
    //Sobreescribir función de navegación hacia atrás
    this.getOwnerComponent().getService("ShellUIService").then(function(oShellService) {
        oShellService.setBackNavigation(function() {
            console.log("NAVBACK!!! LAUNCHPAD!!!");
        });                
    });
}
```

This kind of works... It console logs when navigating back but just in the main app, what i need is having a handler in the custom tile.

I don't know if what i'm doing is wrong or if there's another approach to this problem.

Comment: While this does not directly answer your question, it is possible to automatically refresh a dynamic tile every X seconds (I think the default is every 10 seconds). This can be configured for each tile in the Portal service.

Comment: @Marc That workaround surely helps man! I will definitely try it

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to do this after a while...

Whenever you want to handle any navigation related event in UI5, you have to use the router object, as described at the UI5 documentation (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5)

To resume it, the router object is alive during the User's session, across all launchpad's apps. It listens to URL changes and compare it to the active app's manifest routes, looking for a match. If there's no match, then the **bypassed** event is fired.

So, if you nav-back from an application to the launchpad's **home view**, the router will change and, therefore, seek a match, firing the bypassed event.

To handle this event, in your custom tile app you have to:

1- Create a Router Object when initiating the app:

```
onInit: function(){
...
    let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
...
}
```

2- Add a handle to the bypassed event:

```
{
    ...
    oRouter.attachBypassed(this.onBackFromApp, this);
},

onBackFromApp: function(oEvent){           
    if (oEvent.getParameter("hash") === "Shell-home"){
        this.actualizarNumeroDeDocumentos();
    }
}
```

This will make the app fire the onBackFromApp() function whenever the hash of the router is "Shell-home", the same as the launchpad's home.